# Как в представлении задать дополнительное условие?

Tags: sql

Есть представление:

```
SELECT m.item_id, i.title, SUM(m.mcount) as amount, i.price, sh.title as shtitle
FROM movements m, items i, shelves sh
WHERE sh.id=i.shelf_id 
AND m.item_id=i.id group by m.item_id
--AND amount > 0
```

Как отфильтровать записи, в которых `SUM(m.mcount)` равно 0?

Comment: юзайте having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте после group by

```
having SUM(m.mcount)=0
```

[HAVING](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html)